# Altium Rename net label, auto update its connection

Tags: altium

I have many net labels in schematics, now I want to rename some of them. But when I do, it doesn't update other net labels with same name.

Lets say I have 5 connection with 1 net label "Pin1", now I want to change it to "Pin5". Is there any way, that I change one and it updates all other 4. Yes there is Smart Edit replace, but that seems a trick and not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the net label, right click on it, then select *Find Similar Objects* at the top of the list.

This window will appear:
[image]

Select *SAME* for both *Object Kind* and *Text*. Now tick *Select Matching* at the bottom of the window and hit OK.

This action will highlight and select all net labels whose name is *pin 1*.

Press F11 to open up the SCH inspector and change the text from *pin 1* to whatever you like.

Done!

You can use "Find Similar Objects" function with every type of object in Altium, even in the PCB Editor.

Comment: This only works for me when I also tick the `Select Matching` checkbox

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is the search and *replace* dialog shortcut for Altium. Additionally, you can restrict the scope of the search to just net identifiers.

If you want to change 'Pin1' to 'Pin5', just use a simple text replacement.

If your concern is accidentally matching 'Pin11' in your search for 'Pin1', the "Whole word option" of the search (and search/replace) dialog is intended for exactly that purpose.

Alternatively, you can use the 'SCH List' panel to edit multiple items in parallel (right click, -> "Switch to Edit Mode"). It also has facilities for limiting the scope (set it to include only net labels).

Comment: yes but it could be problem if other net has pin1 in name too. I was thinking to have something like refactoring, where a dialogs pops and updates only specific connection, no matter what name is.

Comment: If you want to search for 'Pin1' and *not* 'Pin11', just check the 'Whole word only' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the *SCH Filter* tab from the Panels Menu.

Insert: **StringText = 'TX**' to find and select all labels and power ports with that name. Select scope current document or all documents to rename labels in more than one doc.
Use *SCH List* to see the selected items. Select properties and change the name.

You can use **(IsNetLabel) AND (StringText = 'TX')** if you only want to select net labels or **(IsPowerObject)** for power objects.
When using **(StringText = 'TX') OR (Name = 'TX')** then also ports should be selected.